# Requested texture size [0x0] is invalid. error when i am loading image in browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tensorflow.js

Tensorflow.js error in browser while calling predict function

I'm using Node.js to run the webapp. This is my scripts I have included and I'm running Node.js in Chrome and not able to solve the error.

This project has 7 classes as output that is dense layer in output of shape 1x7.

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js
```

This is my JavaScript file.

```
 $(document).on('change', '#file', function() {

    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload= function(){
        let dataUrl = reader.result;
        $('#selected-image').attr('src',dataUrl);
        $('#type1-predict').empty();
        $('#type2-predict').empty();
        $('#type3-predict').empty();
        $('#type4-predict').empty();
        $('#type5-predict').empty();
        $('#type6-predict').empty();
        $('#type7-predict').empty();
    }

    let file = $('#file').prop('files')[0];
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    });
    const CANCER_CLASSES = {
    0:"Actinic Keratoses",
    1:"Basal cell carcinoma",
    2:"Benign keratosis",
    3:"Dermatofibroma",
    4:"Melanoma",
    5:"Melanocytic nevi",
    6:"Vascular skin",    
    }
    let model;
    (async function(){
    model= await tf.loadLayersModel('http://localhost:81/model/model.json');
    $('#pro').hide()

    })();
    $(document).on('click', '#predict-button', async function() { 
    let image = $('#selected-image').get(0);

    let tensor = 
    tf.browser.fromPixels(image)
        .resizeNearestNeighbor([224,224])
        .toFloat()
        .expandDims();
    let prediction = await model.predict(tensor).data();
    let top3 = Array.from(prediction)
    .map(function(p,i){
        return {
            probab: p,
            classname:CANCER_CLASSES[i]
        };

    }).sort(function(a,b){
        return b.probab-a.probab;
    }).slice(0,4);
    $("#type1-predict").empty();
    top3.forEach(function(p){
        $('#type1-predict').append(`<li>${p.classname}: 
    ${p.probab.tpFixed(6)} 
    </li>`);
    });
    });
```

This is a snippet of the HTML file

```
<body>
<div id="pro" class="progress progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress- 
bar-animated"></div>    
<input type="file" id="image-selector">
<button id="predict-button">Predict</button>
<p style="font-weight:bold">Presentation</p>
<p>Actinic Keratoses : <span id="type1-predict"></span></p>
<p>Basal cell carcinoma: <span id="type2-predict"></span></p>
<p>Benign keratosis: <span id="type3-predict"></span></p>
<p>Dermatofibroma: <span id="type4-predict"></span></p>
 <p>Melanoma: <span id="type5-predict"></span></p>
<p>Melanocytic nevi : <span id="type6-predict"></span></p>
<p>Vascular skin: <span id="type7-predict"></span></p>
<img id="selected-image" src="">
```

Could you help me resolve the following error:

```
 webgl_util.ts:203 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Requested texture size 
    [0x0] is invalid.
    at Fr (webgl_util.ts:203)
    at oi (gpgpu_util.ts:126)
    at ui (gpgpu_util.ts:173)
    at t.createUnsignedBytesMatrixTexture (gpgpu_context.ts:134)
    at t.acquireTexture (texture_manager.ts:71)
    at t.acquireTexture (backend_webgl.ts:2472)
    at t.uploadToGPU (backend_webgl.ts:2407)
    at t.getTexture (backend_webgl.ts:566)
    at t.fromPixels (backend_webgl.ts:254)
    at t.fromPixels (engine.ts:599)
```

Comment: It's possible prediction was length 0 and not found. check if it's >0 before doing anything else. I had this issue in my code and just wrapped it in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 13):

**Problem**

When Tensorflow.js tries to transform your image into a tensor via [`tf.browser.fromPixels`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#browser.fromPixels), it [reads](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-core/blob/f1843372cac3ef25f0fc3e95e4db55a06d47d595/tfjs-webgpu/src/backend_webgpu.ts#L614) the `width` and `height` from the DOM element. As these values are not set in your case, you receive an error.

**Solution**

You have to give the `img` tag a `width` and `height` attribute, so that Tensorflow.js knows the size of your image:

```html
<img id="selected-image" src="" width="..." height="...">
```

There is currently an [open issue in the repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/322) describing this problem. This might be fixed in the future by providing a better error message.

Answer (score 0):

my issue using React and Tensorflow was that the outer div(containing the video element) didn't have height and width setup eg:

```
<div id="container" className="h-[460] w-[380]">
  <video id="myWebcam" width={380} height={460}></video>
</div>
```