# Error: Requested texture size [0x0] is invalid

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm using Tensorflow JS to run an object detection model using the browser's webcam.
I get this error when running `model.detect`:

```
Error: Requested texture size [0x0] is invalid
```

I have seen [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662313/requested-texture-size-0x0-is-invalid-error-when-i-am-loading-image-in-browse) but as you can see in the code below, the video element does have a width and height.

Here is the complete code:

```js
const { createApp } = Vue

createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      myModel: undefined
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('mounted')
    const _this = this;
    cocoSsd.load().then((loadedModel) => {
      console.log('loaded')
      _this.myModel = loadedModel;
    });
     
  },
  methods: {
    enableCam(event) {
      const _this = this;
      const video = document.getElementById('webcam');
      console.log(video);
      const constraints = {
        video: true,
        width: 500,
        height: 500
      };
    
      // Activate the webcam stream.
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then((stream) => {
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.addEventListener('loadeddata', _this.predictWebcam());
      });
    },
    predictWebcam() {
      const _this = this;
      const video = document.getElementById('webcam');
      console.log(video);

      this.myModel.detect(video).then(function (predictions) {
        console.log(predictions);
        window.requestAnimationFrame(_this.predictWebcam());
      });
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 2em;
  color: #3D3D3D;
}

h1 {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #FF6F00;
}

video {
  display: block;
}

section {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.removed {
  display: none;
}

.invisible {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.camView {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.camView p {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 111, 0, 0.85);
  color: #FFF;
  border: 1px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.highlighter {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25);
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
  </head>  
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <h1 v-if="myModel === undefined">
        Model is loading ... wait
      </h1>

      
      <section id="demos">
        
        <div id="liveView" class="camView">
          <button @click="enableCam" id="webcamButton">Enable Webcam</button>
          <video id="webcam" autoplay muted width="640" height="480"></video>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
   

    <!-- Import TensorFlow.js library -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/tf.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Load the coco-ssd model to use to recognize things in images -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd"></script>
    
    <!-- Import the page's JavaScript -->
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a different known issue that would raise this error?

Answer (score 0):

Got bad news for you, it is a Vue 3 issue.

I've been tracking this issue for some time now, and the only workaround I could find is to draw the video as canvas, and then pass the canvas to the detector.

Everything else is futile, even explicitly and redundantly set the video element hight and width.

This was a deal breaker for me, so moved to React.

best luck!